# Index of underlying string when parsing tokens in boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I was wondering if it's possible to get the index value of the underlying string when parsing using boost tokens.

word_count_lexer is a boost::spirit::lex::lexer
Here is my sample code:

```
base_iterator first = str.begin();
base_iterator last = str.end();
lexer_type::iterator_type iter = word_count_lexer.begin(first, last);
lexer_type::iterator_type end = word_count_lexer.end();
while (iter != end && token_is_valid(*iter)) {
    if(iter->id() == ID_WORD) {
       std::cout << iter->value() << std::endl;
    }
    ++iter;
    ++w;
}
```

What I want to accomplish: in my while loop I would like to have access to the index of the match. I was thinking something like

```
std::distance(str.begin(), it)
```

but this doesn't work here because of it type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a discussion regarding this topic [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.parsers.spirit.general/19767).
Ultimately I changed my approach and used a different parsing strategy.